# How do I a grab a parameter within a document MONGODB (C#)

Tags: c#, mongodb

i have the following problem, i filtered the collection to get the specific document in collection which i need. The document inside it has some variable with some values. How do i grab the specific variable and its value from the specific document.

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
var db = client.GetDatabase("myfirstdb");
var collection = db.GetCollection<PlayerInfo>("players");
var filter = Builders<PlayerInfo>.Filter.Eq("playerName", player.Name);
//find in document filter the parameter "isAdmin" and grab its value.
```

[This is how my document looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKYYw.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Project` clause when you perform the find operation on the filter. Below code will do.

```
bool isAdmin = collection.Find(filter).Project(x => x.isAdmin).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I am going to try it and let you know.

Comment: It works.. can you explain it a little? i am new to mongodb.

Comment: It's just a simple projection. As the name suggests, the `Project()` method returns only the elements we want from the document. You just needed `isAdmin` so we just projected that property, if you want to project more properties you use the new clause to map into a class like
`collection.Find(filter).Project(x => new object {
isAdmin =  x.isAdmin,
id =x.id,
name=x.name})
.FirstOrDefault();`
And this will return an object with `isAdmin, id, name` properties. 
Find clause will just query the collection on the filter and FirstOrDefault() will return first result.